# How to get the shortest country name from an array in C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

My program below gives me shortest country character count from a string array. How do I retrieve shortest country name at same time using Linq? So I want retrieve UK name at same time I find shortest country character count.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string[] countries = { "India", "USA", "UK" };

        var minCount = countries.Min(x => x.Length);
        var maxCount = countries.Max(x => x.Length);

        Console.WriteLine
            ("The shortest country name has {0} characters in its name", minCount);
        Console.WriteLine
            ("The longest country name has {0} characters in its name", maxCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just order all countries by name length and take the first (for the shortest) and the last (for the longest):

```
string[] countries = { "India", "USA", "UK" };
var ordered = countries.OrderBy(x => x.Length);
var min = ordered.First();
var max = ordered.Last();

//"The shortest country name is UK, it has 2 characters in its name"
Console.WriteLine("The shortest country name is {0}, it has {1} characters in its name",
    min, min.Length);

//"The longest country name is India, it has 5 characters in its name"
Console.WriteLine("The longest country name is {0}, it has {1} characters in its name",
    max, max.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is order your array by  name `Length`:

```
  string[] countries = { "India", "USA", "UK" };
  var shortestCountry= countries.OrderBy(s=>s.Length).First();
```

With the `shortestCountry` you have both things that you need.

Another way could be using [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548651(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
string[] countries = { "India", "USA", "UK" };
var shortestCountry = chrs2.Aggregate((seed, e) => seed.Length < e.Length ? seed :  e);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question already has an accepted answer which is perfectly adequate for the specific example given but anyone else reading this should keep in mind that it doesn't scale as well as it should. OrderBy results in an ordered sort of the data set which executes in O(n log n), whereas the problem can be solved with a single pass through the data set resulting in an execution order of O(n). I suggest downloading the [morelinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library (also available via NuGet) which provides the `MinBy` extension to do precisely this.

Alternatively you can do yourself in O(n) with Aggregate as octaviocci has already pointed out.